# should I nest when ICC and number of units is low?

Tags: mixed-model

Let's say that I have 10 regions and 50 schools in each region.
I run two models (`region <- DV ~ 1 + (1|region)` and `school <- DV ~ 1 + (1|school)`) against the null model and find that the ICC for the `region` model is `0.08`, whereas for the `school` model is `0.34`.

Clearly variance among schools is more important than among regions.
However schools are nested within regions, and there are arguably a sufficient number of them to warrant a mixed model.

Would you still nest `school` within `region`? I often read that it's more important to have a large number of Level 2 units as Level 1 units. However region has way fewer units than schools...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would fit the model:

```
DV ~ 1 + (1 | region / school)
```

It is not unusual to find much lower variation at higher geo-spatial levels. It is always good to have as many groups as possible (within reason) but you can only work with what you have, and 10 is sufficient in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Robert Long. But wouldn't it be better to ensure that the highest level has the greatest number of units to make estimates more reliable? After all, the ICC is much larger for school than region, and it's debatable whether an ICC of 0.08 is actually meaningful. Also, why is it that we usually find lower variation at the higher levels? Has it something to do with `n`, or some other mixed-model peculiarity?

Comment: Yes, it would be "better" to ensure that you have more regions. It would be "better" still to conduct a controlled experiment / trial. As I mentioned, you can only work with what you have. If you have the possibility to sample vastly more regions, then by all means do so. As for the ICC, first it's not clear how you detemined the ICC is 0.08. Usually you fit the 3-level model and compare the variation at each level to the total. Anyway, it *may* be debatable whether 0.08 is meaningful. But what is meaningful ? 0.1 ? 0.15 ? If it's 0.15, then why ? And what if it's 0.14999 ?